# How to fit f(x)=a*sin^2(b*x^2 + c) in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting

I have to fit f(x) = a*sin^2(b*x^2 + c) to the graph with mesurements:

3       0.007
36      0.0027
94      0.0026
124     0.0025
153     0.0024
185     0.0022
213     0.0021
273     0.0021
285     0.0022
309     0.0025
318     0.0027
327     0.003
327     0.0031
358     0.0044
390     0.0071
407     0.0096
451     0.0191
477     0.026
510     0.04
543     0.0532
566     0.0645
598     0.0778
623     0.0875
641     0.091
687     0.089
713     0.079
738     0.065
779     0.035
801     0.016
824     0.007
848     0.0037
872     0.0085
888     0.016
906     0.033
915     0.041
936     0.057
942     0.06
954     0.069
974     0.079
991     0.084
1000    0.085

Can samebody help me fit that curve to my graph? Thank you in advance!

All I get is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baQJ8.png)

Comment: is your data just like this or is it organized in two columns? Please always post your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a good fit always provide some best guess initial values.
And I guess it probably facilitates the whole fitting procedure if the argument of `sin()` is roughly in the range of -pi to +pi, that's why the guess value for `b` is in the order of `1e-6`.

**Code:**

```
###  fit sin(x)**2 function
reset session

$Data <<EOD
3    0.007
36   0.0027
94   0.0026
124  0.0025
153  0.0024
185  0.0022
213  0.0021
273  0.0021
285  0.0022
309  0.0025
318  0.0027
327  0.003
327  0.0031
358  0.0044
390  0.0071
407  0.0096
451  0.0191
477  0.026
510  0.04
543  0.0532
566  0.0645
598  0.0778
623  0.0875
641  0.091
687  0.089
713  0.079
738  0.065
779  0.035
801  0.016
824  0.007
848  0.0037
872  0.0085
888  0.016
906  0.033
915  0.041
936  0.057
942  0.06
954  0.069
974  0.079
991  0.084
1000 0.085
EOD

a=0.1
b=4e-6
c=0.01
f(x) = a*sin(b*x**2 + c)**2

set fit nolog
fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via a,b,c

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 title "Data", \
     f(x) w l lc rgb "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
a               = 0.0896193        +/- 0.002625     (2.929%)
b               = 5.0613e-06       +/- 6.487e-08    (1.282%)
c               = -0.471368        +/- 0.03562      (7.557%)
```

[image]